# c++ free memory allocation in constructor when facing exception

Tags: c++, exception, memory, memory-management, constructor

I found some interesting behavior in the case of exception when construct an object:

```
class bookentry
{
public:
    bookentry(){
      t1.reset(new test1);       //0 
      test1 *t11 = new test1;    //1
      test2 *t22 = new test2;    //2
      throw 1;                   //3
    }
protected:
private:
  auto_ptr<test1> t1;
  auto_ptr<test2> t2;
};
```

From what I test:

If we throw an exception from ***test2's constructor (#2)***, then

1. **t1** : will be fully destroyed, i.e. t1's destructor will called, and memory will be freed.
2. **t11**: will never be destroyed (neither calling t11's destructor or freeing memory).
3. **t22**: this is funny part, t22's destructor will not be called which is right, but **t22's memory will be freed!**

If we throw an exception from **bookentry's constructor (#3)**,this time, things will be a litter different: **t22** will never be destroyed (neither calling t22's destructor or freeing memory), t11 is same as above

I am just confused with the sentence at #2

> test2 *t22 = new test2;    //2

*It seems* that when we throw an exception from class constructor, and new expression will make sure that corresponding delete is called, **but** any object that fully created via new expression before that exception will be leaked(t11, or t11 and t22 if we throw an exception at #3).

so, if we write codes like below and the 5th object construction failed:

> test2 *t2s = new test2[10];

then, it seems it's a litter bit safer:

1. the already constructed objects will be destroyed,
2. the memory will be freed.

My questions, is this standard c++ behavior? I just test msvc 2012 and gcc 4.4.6, both looks implementing such mechanism.

**Edit**
TO make my question more clearly:

In some case you need write code like t1.reset(new test1)[see #1 in my codes] in other normal functions. In such case, if an exception is thrown from constructor. How can I reason about the program state? is there any memory leak?

**My test make sure** these is no memory leaks in such case, but is it  standard c++ behavior?

Comment: MSVC 2012 definitely supports `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. I'll bet that version of GCC does as well. Use those whenever you can instead of `std::auto_ptr`, as it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is simple:
***All the objects completely created in that scope will be destroyed***
The above rule does not apply to raw pointers pointing to objects allocated on dynamic storage(*allocated with `new`*). They need to be explicitly `delete`d. When you use `new` you explicitly own the resource management and it is your job to call the `delete` to release the resource and the compiler won't do it for you.

---

**Good Read:**

**[Constructor failures - Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm)**

---

Note that the best way to manage resources in C++ is by using RAII and smart pointers. More so in constructors. Instead of using any raw pointers simply wrap them in smart pointers and they will automagically do the resource management for your object in case of such exceptions. You have just experienced this power when you used `auto_ptr` in your code example as opposed to the raw pointers.

Comment: NO, you didn't understand my question. in some case you need write code like t1.reset(new test1) see #1 in my codes, and this may be in other normal functions. In this case, if an exception is thrown from constructor. How can I reason about the program state? is there any memory leak?

Comment: @Chang: You haven't read the answer or the link included in the answer. If you do you will find the answer to your question.

Comment: I absolutely read that article, not now but also 10 years ago. c++ standard is changed twice(03 and 11). in example 2b, if you have only one new expression in initializer-list, then it seems be safe now.

Comment: Re: "The above rule does not apply to raw pointers" - another way to think of it is that the rule **does** apply to raw pointers; the destructor of a pointer does not do anything.